# Scheduler browser task without window opening

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I got some scheduled python scripts which are running 2 times daily, to do some routine jobs. The problem is that sometimes the tasks starts when i use the computer. Some of the tasks have to open browsers, and this is happening while i am working on another thing. For some of the tasks, i am using :

```
script.py > NUL 2>&1
```

But the problem is, that this method doesn't prevent the browsers to open while i am working.

Also tried with different user in the task scheduler, but then the task doesn't even start. Any suggestions what to do ?

Comment: In the task scheduler window you can set it to run only if the computer is idle, I'd do that.

Comment: Hey @C.Lewis . I know about that option, but i need to run the tasks at fixed time. And at that time, i am using the computer.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to help you then. If it won't run with a different user account and you can't wait till the computer is idle, there's no workaround. I think you need to focus on figuring out why it won't run on another user account. Have you set "run whether user is logged in or not"?